# What were the topics of discussion which Jesus had at the Temple? (Catholic perspective)

Tags: catholicism, gospel-of-luke, historical-jesus

Luke 2:42-47 (RSVCE) has this narrative:

" And when he was twelve years old, they went up according to custom;  and when the feast was ended, as they were returning, the boy Jesus stayed behind in Jerusalem. His parents did not know it,  but supposing him to be in the company they went a day’s journey, and they sought him among their kinsfolk and acquaintances;  and when they did not find him, they returned to Jerusalem, seeking him.  After three days they found him in the temple, sitting among the teachers, listening to them and asking them questions;  and all who heard him were amazed at his understanding and his answers. "

I would like to know what were the possible topics of discussion which Jesus had with the teachers. Has the Catholic Church ever come out with a speculative list of topics of the discussion of young Jesus at the temple ?

Answer (score 2):

No.

Any list would be purely speculative, but boy-oh-boy does the mind and heart soar with the possibilities.  One imagines the boy Jesus getting in touch with his devine nature and the questions his man-nature would have formed.

I hope that heaven allows for exploring these questions.  One could imagine seeking out one of those temple teachers that were there and getting a first-hand account of that conversation.